# Distribute nodes into two groups on a force diagram layout (left and right)

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have some data that Im trying to plot in a specific way:
all the nodes have a way to identify which group it belongs, let say *position:L* or *position:R*.

I would like to take that property into account an order all the "l" (left) nodes to be on the left of a central node and all of the "R" (right) nodes to be on the right hand side of a static central node (something similar like drawn in the picture [image]).

Previously Ive used this:

```
tick = function () {

    nodes.forEach(function (n) {
        if (n.position == "L") {
            n.x -= force.alpha() * 80;
        }
        if (n.position == "R") {
            n.x += force.alpha() * 80;
        }
    });
```

....
    };

This solution was okay for small sets but when nodes reach a certain number, say a 1000+, it becomes a very expensive one. 
Ive looked at these two examples:
[1st one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953) and [2nd one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919) and I was wondering maybe I could solve may problem with combining couple of forces on the page trying to "tear" the (static) central node apart and pulling different nodes to the sides ?

Any suggestions are welcome, thank You.

Comment: You probably want a [multi-focus force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for Your comment but unfortunetely thats the same logic Ive used before which doesn't solve the performance problem of having 1000+ nodes